# Why doesn't this CSS transition work?

Tags: css

Is this a solid, cross-browser way to implement transitions? I have no idea what I could be doing wrong?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C83Yd/)

html:

```
<div id="sideBar">
    <ul class="sideMenu">
        <li><a href="#">Beat of the Day</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Cyborg DB</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Hadiaris.com</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">DriversEd.com</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Controlco</a>           
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">GGP</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">TVA</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

css:

```
.sideMenu a {
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 10px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    color: black;
    -moz-transition: color .9s, -moz-transform .9s;
    -webkit-transition: color .9s, -moz-transform .9s;
    -o-transition: color .9s, -moz-transform .9s;
    transition: color .9s, -moz-transform .9s; 
}
.sideMenu a:hover {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px 0px black;
    color: blue;
}
```

Comment: css transitions work on "some" browsers

Comment: Internet Explorer 10 and upwards support CSS3 Transition.

Comment: @blachawk I am using Chrome on windows8, so it should be working, other transitions on my page are working with similar implementation.

Comment: Do you just want the color to fade transition to blue?

Comment: @JohnTobin Yes, with no Javascript.

Comment: Then all you need is `transition: color ease 1s;` (for each vendor prefix)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get rid of `, -moz-transform .9s` in the transition declaration.

```
.sideMenu a {
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 10px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    color: black;
    -moz-transition: color .9s;
    -webkit-transition: color .9s;
    -o-transition: color .9s;
    transition: color .9s; 
}
.sideMenu a:hover {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px 0px black;
    color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `transform` values are all using the `-moz-` version. Also, your transition will only work when "unhovering" the way you have it. If you add the transitions to both rules, you'll get the transform on the hover as well.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HvvjC/)

```
.sideMenu a {
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 10px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    color: black;
    -moz-transition: color .9s, -moz-transform .9s;
    -webkit-transition: color .9s, -webkit-transform .9s;
    -o-transition: color .9s, -o-transform .9s;
    transition: color .9s, transform .9s; 
}
.sideMenu a:hover {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px 0px black;
    color: blue;

    -moz-transition: color .9s, -moz-transform .9s;
    -webkit-transition: color .9s, -webkit-transform .9s;
    -o-transition: color .9s, -o-transform .9s;
    transition: color .9s, transform .9s;
}
```

Comment: Not true: "Also, your transition will only work when "unhovering" the way you have it." If the transition is applied to the `a` (without pseudo) it applies always. An `a:hover` is still an `a`. Like all other properties.

Answer (score 1):

Your `-moz-transform` is causing problems. If you just want to animate the `color` property, you can remove it:

```
    -moz-transition: color .9s;
    -webkit-transition: color .9s;
    -o-transition: color .9s;
    transition: color .9s; 
}
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/C83Yd/1/**